# Yii2 GridView Triger filter only on click

Tags: gridview, filter, yii2

I use GridView widget with filters,

The problem is, i want the filtering to be triggered only on a button click

```
$(document).on('click touch', '.search_button', function(){
    $("#grid-id").yiiGridView("applyFilter");
});
```

Ok, this work, but how disable filtering on the change focus to another field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it

```
$(document).off('change.yiiGridView keydown.yiiGridView','#grid-id-filters input, #grid-id-filters select');
```